# warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]

Tags: c, string-literals, json-c

I am getting this weird error below

```
json.c:81:19: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by  default]
json.c:81:3: error: missing terminating " character
json.c:82:32: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘:’ token
json.c:90:22: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
json.c:90:21: error: missing terminating " character
```

CODE:

```
int main()
{
  char * string = "{
                  "sender" : "joys of programming",

                   "receiver": [ "123",
                                 "345",
                                 "654",
                                 "432"
                               ]

                }";
 printf("JSON string: %sn", string);
 json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(string);
 json_parse(jobj);
 return 0;
 }
```

I understood error is about `char * string` line. But don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Don't you need to escape?

Comment: I tried escaping inner double quotes by adding "\" infront of each ,I am getting this error `error: stray "\" in program`

Comment: each of the parts of the string should be ended with something similar to "\n" \   Notice the trailing back slash.   To make it easy for you, suggest writing a table of pointers to char strings,  Then using a vary long string buffer, pass each line of the json commands into that buffer using one call to `strcpy()` and and several calls to `strcat()`   be sure to include all the necessary escaped double quotes and include `\n` where ever a newline is needed, including at the end of the accumulated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to:

1. to escape `"` char because of it is a special char used to define a
   C-String literal.
2. For multi line strings you must define each line as a single C-String using `""` for each one

So, the resulting code is

```
  char * string = "{"
                  "\"sender\" : \"joys of programming\","
                  "\"receiver\": [ \"123\","
                                  "\"345\","
                                  "\"654\","
                                  "\"432\""
                                "]"
                 "}";
```

Comment: this answer is missing the newline characters between each line of the json command

Comment: @user3629249 I proposed a solution for the OP problem. I didn't tried to use the command using json.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use escape character when using quotations marks inside quotation marks.

```
  char * string = "{ "
                  "\"sender\" : \"joys of programming\"," 

                   "\"receiver\": [ \"123\","
                                   "\"345\","
                                   "\"654\","
                                   "\"432\""
                               "]"

                "}";
```

This is going to do it.

Comment: I tried escaping inner double quotes by adding "\" infront of each ,I am getting this error `error: stray "\" in program`

Comment: This is what I get as an output when I print it out: 
{ "sender" : "joys of programming","receiver": [ "123","345","654","432"]}